# Future Career Opportunities for UI/UX Developers

Tags: new-job, recruitment, software-development, job-description

I'm an IT specialization Student and I'm interested in frontend  development I have no idea about these fields can anyone give me a broad idea if UI/UX is good or have more career opportunities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome new user,

- On Stackoverflow, click "Jobs" button to your left. You can see the market for UX jobs. Also check the two or three other places where such jobs are listed. There is no way to know more about the market for UX jobs than doing that. If you spend an hour looking at it, you will know as much as anyone else.
- As you can see there are an incredible number of UX related projects, and there is huge demand in general for www/ux to be built.
- Be aware that design jobs **are for designers**. That is to say, you can't "learn to sing" and you can't "learn to be a great illustrator or designer".  For example, I know everything there is to know about eps files technically, but, I couldn't draw or design a logo to save my life.
- Be aware that while there are a huge number of UX/www jobs around, **there are also a huge number of people doing it**. Subsequently it is not perhaps the very highest paid field (although you'll do just fine, and you'll always have work.)
- Be aware that (much like being "a programmer"), technology around ux/www *changes continually, forever, and every 6 months or so*.  If you become really good at Express or something, that will go out the window and there will be some new fad. So for your career of 40 years from now, you will continually, endlessly, without end, have to figure out new systems, languages etc - continually. Always. Every 6 months.
- **BUT MOSTLY BE AWARE THAT** much like programming, **it is very hard to "get a start"** in ux/www. There are 100s questions on here from ux-types (also from programmers) that "It's been over a year and I can't get my first break."

Best of luck.